# Randomize text, embed codes and URL's from list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with movie titles, youtube URL's (with which I can construct an embed code) and URL's to IMDB. On every page refresh, another movie title, Youtube video, and text with a URL to IMDB has to appear.

```
["Movie A", "URL_to_youtube_movie_A", "URL_to_IMDB_movie_A"],
["Movie B", "URL_to_youtube_movie_B", "URL_to_IMDB_movie_B"],
etc.
```

My website already has a refresh button: the page reloads with `<a href="javascript:history.go(0)"></a>`. How can I make the youtube video displayed randomized? I want the output to be HTML, so I can add elements afterwards, if necessary.

Comment: A simpler method to reload the page would be `location.reload();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle the array, you can use underscore, or write custom function:

```
list = _.shuffle(list)
```

then output first n movies. This is the simplest method, that I think will be good enough for your case.

I would make an array of objects. Movie is an object, like this:

```
var list = [{ title: "Movie A", urlYouTube: "URL_to_youtube_movie", urlImdb: "URL_to_IMDB_movie_A"}, ...]
```

Also if you plan to do more operations than just show the random movies look at some javascript frameworks(backbone.js, angular, ...).

I would recommend you to use templates for the HTML output. Underscore also has simple template implementation. _.template(templateString, [data], [settings])

Something like this: [DEMO && CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/hd3YL/5/)

Comment: Great, seems like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

With simple javascript without any Library 
You will need suffle function like below
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/adUdX/)

```
function arrayShuffle(oldArray) {
    var newArray = oldArray.slice();
    var len = newArray.length;
    var i = len;
     while (i--) {
        var p = parseInt(Math.random()*len);
        var t = newArray[i];
        newArray[i] = newArray[p];
        newArray[p] = t;
    }
    return newArray; 
};
```

Call it like

```
  var list = [{ title: "Movie A", urlYouTube: "URL_to_youtube_movie_A", urlImdb: "URL_to_IMDB_movie_A"}, 
                { title: "Movie B", urlYouTube: "URL_to_youtube_movie_B", urlImdb: "URL_to_IMDB_movie_B"}, 
                { title: "Movie C", urlYouTube: "URL_to_youtube_movie_C", urlImdb: "URL_to_IMDB_movie_C"}];

   var Suffledlist = arrayShuffle(list);
```

And then show top 2 or 5 elements